# I am getting error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol (C++ code)

Tags: c++

1) D:\imp\msgList\fun1.cpp

```
CMLMessage::MLMessageStatus CMLMessage::getInformationBlocks(const TBase::TLocale& fallbackLocale )
  {
     CDatabaseHelper::setfallBackLocale(fallbackLocale); // setter function
  }
```

2) D:\imp\commonfolder\fun2.cpp

```
class CDatabaseHelper
{
  Public:
         static void setfallBackLocale(TBase::TLocale fallbackLocale)
          { 
            mfallbackLocale = fallbackLocale;
           }
  Private:
           static TBase::TLocale mfallbackLocale; // class member 
}
```

Compiler giving Error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct TBase::TLocale NTrafficInformation::CDatabaseHelper::mfallbackLocale" (?mfallbackLocale@CDatabaseHelper@NTrafficInformation@@0UTLocale@TBase@@A)
```

Hi experts Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, next time throw the error message at a websearch before asking, the problem and solutions are known.

Comment: The code given wont even compile, please give a [mre]

Comment: You need to provide a definition of your static member, see the linked duplicate for details

Answer (score 0):

In `fun2.cpp`, you need to initialize that static member with something like:

```
TBase::TLocale CDatabaseHelper::mfallbackLocale = TBase::TLocale{"C"};
```

where the right-hand side is any valid expression producing a `TLocale`.  This line should go after the class definition.

See the [cppreference page on "static members"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) for alternative ways to declare/define that static member.

Comment: Certainly.  If this has helped, take a look at this topic in the Help Center:  [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)